# Using a chunk oriented step with two different resources

Tags: spring-batch

I'm trying to configure a chunk oriented step in Spring Batch where I access two different resources: a JMS queue, and a JDBC data source.

I'm not, as of now, worried about dealing with *distributed transactions*. However, I **do want** spring to deal with commit and rolling back the transaction. In other words, I just want to inject the DataSource's and have spring commit them after every chunk is processed.

What is the best, and most simple way of doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to create a chunked batch with an [JmsItemReader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/jms/JmsItemReader.html) subclass to read  and a database writer such as [JdbcBatchItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html) or [HibernateItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernateItemWriter.html).

Comment: And what if I have to *read* both from a database and a JMS queue?

Comment: probably it would be better to do that in two steps, I don't think there is anything out of the box for that. `MultiResourceItemReader` exists but it's for example for reading from two sources of the same type. but you can write an ItemReader that takes the to ItemReaders you need as input, keep reading until they're different and pass the result back to the ItemWriter, or split the job in two, one to emty the queue into a database table, and the second job to read from both tables using `MultiResourceItemReader`